# I have two tables both A and B. I want to insert data from table B to A using an inner join

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have two tables `country` and `country_list`. Both have similar columns and content, I want to transfer all of the country codes(`country_code` column) from the `country_list` table and insert the data into all matching countries in the country table which also has a `country_code` column but is empty. I have an idea about where to start by inner joining the `country_name` columns because they have similar values, but which is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try an update join:

```
UPDATE country c
INNER JOIN country_list cl
    ON c.country_name = cl.country_name
SET
    c.country_code = cl.country_code;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **INSERT** statement with **INNER JOIN**:-

```
INSERT INTO country (country_code)
SELECT country_code from country_list countryList
INNER JOIN country c ON c.country_name = countryList.country_name;
```